# MySQL Views and Column Name Case Sensitivity

Tags: mysql

This might sounds like a simple question, but the one that I haven't been able to find a satisfying answer to.

In MySQL, if you are using a Unix Based machines, the tables names and column names are case in-sensitive when running the queries as long as you follow Camel Case in the names.

Now, here is the tricky part, Lets assume the following table structure.

```
> desc table1
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

> desc table2
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name1 | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

> desc table_view
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name1 | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, if I run the Queries on my table with column names mentioned in Upper case, the result will have the column name in Upper case and Lower case, if the query has lower case column names.

```
> select name from table1
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| test  |
| test2 |
+-------+

> select NAME from table1
+-------+
| NAME  |
+-------+
| test  |
| test2 |
+-------+
```

However, when I run the same queries on the View, the column names match the case of the string that were used while creating the view. i.e. the resulting data will have the same column as the view and not what is used in the query.

```
> select name from table_view
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| test  |
| test2 |
+-------+

> select NAME from table_view
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| test  |
| test2 |
+-------+
```

Is there is an easy way to fix this problem and make sure that the views also follow the same standard or format as the tables would when responding with query results ?

PS : We have some legacy code where we are running out of Table Row Size limit when creating new tables due to the number and size of the Columns. So we split them dynamically into n tables and joined them into a view with the same name as previous table to make sure we didn't have to do much of a code change.

But the case issue with the view is breaking things. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is one of those really frustrating edge cases that hardly anyone ever encounters. Good luck. :D